# Как сократить расстояние между пальцем и перемещаемой картинкой при реализации перемещения с помощью Drag and Drop

Tags: android, drag-n-drop

Изучаю Drag and Drop, попробовала воспроизвести вот [этот пример](http://findevelop.blogspot.com.by/2012/07/drag-and-drop-android.html)

Все, вроде как, работает, картинки реагируют на нажатия пальца и двигаются в след за ним.

Но вот проблема: при движении пальца картинка тащится за пальцем на расстоянии около 1 см.

Как можно это исправить?